# Google TeamDrive getChildren of a teamDriveID PHP

Tags: php, directory, children

I'm using PHP and the following call to retrieve the top-level TeamDrive folders.

```
$service->teamdrives->listTeamdrives()->getTeamDrives();
```

> Results
>
> TeamDrive1    --- let's say the ID is XXXXXX
>
> TeamDrive2    --- let's say the ID is YYYYYY

TeamDrive1 has a sub-folder called TeamDrive1Sub1 (ID is SSSSS)
then TeamDrive1Sub1 (ID PPPPP) also has a sub-folder etc

I've tried to use the Drive REST API files:List - but this does not seem to work...

I need to find the children "x" levels deep, how do I do that? Maybe some other interface call such as the one I'm using above `$service->teamdrives->listTeamdrives()->getTeamDrives();` which allows me to start at the ID XXXXXX and retrieve it's children

Answer (score 1):

Found my own answer, but there's probably a better way...  if you have the ID of a teamdrive folder and want to get the sub-folders - here's what I have for the PHP code

```
//- first we need to get the $teamDriveId - using the /files/get & the $folderId we passed in

       $folderId = "XXXXXX"  // from above

        $optParams = array(
            'supportsTeamDrives' => true,
        );
        $results = $service->files->get($folderId, $optParams);
        $teamDriveId = $results["teamDriveId"];

        // now we can get the sub-folders (if there are any)
        $params = [
            'q'                     => "'{$folderId}' in parents and trashed = false and mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'",
            'pageSize'              => $pageSize,
            'corpora'               => 'teamDrive',
            'includeTeamDriveItems' => true,
            'supportsTeamDrives'    => true,
            'teamDriveId'           => $teamDriveId,    // this must be the parent Id
            'orderBy'               => 'name',
        ];

        $results = $service->files->listFiles($params);
```

Hope this helps someone