# Where can I find resource methods for Google Drive using php

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I am thoroughly confused!

I am trying to do 3 things in php and Google Drive:

1. List files from Google Drive
2. List shared drives from Google Drive
3. Access the user's email

In the following line of code, I can successfully list folders and files (with help from examples on the net), but I can't seem to find documentation on lines like:

```
$results = $service->files->listFiles($optParams);
```

Which I believe is service/resource/method??

I had hoped that $results = $service->drives->driveList(); would show me shared drives, but to no avail.

**Questions**

1. Can someone point me in a direction to where I can find the methods for use in php, or suggest an alternate way to request the information? The API documentation is written as GET requests.
2. Help me get the email of the user.

The code below does successfully print files and folders, so I do know the authentication works.

Thank you for your help!

```
$client = new Google_Client();

$client->setClientId("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
$client->setClientSecret("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
$client->setRedirectUri("https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.php");
$client->setScopes ( array ( 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.readonly', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email' ) );
$client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile");
$client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email");
//$service = new Google_Service_Oauth2($client);
$service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);

print_r($_SESSION[access_token]);

if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token']) {
    $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);


// Print the names and IDs for up to 10 files from a particular drive.
$optParams = array(
    'corpora' => 'drive',
    'driveId' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    'includeItemsFromAllDrives' => true,
    'pageSize' => 10,
    'supportsAllDrives' => true,
    'fields' => 'nextPageToken, files(id, name)'
);
$results = $service->files->listFiles($optParams);

// print results
foreach ($results->getFiles() as $file){
    echo $file->getName()." ".$file->getId()."<br>";
}

//Print all folders from 'My Drive' 
$optParams = array(
            'fields' => 'nextPageToken, files(id, name, mimeType, modifiedTime, size, parents)',
            'supportsAllDrives' => 'true',
            'q' => "mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'"
        );
        
$results = $service->files->listFiles($optParams);

foreach ($results as $file) {
    echo $file['name'];
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Comment: You can find all the methods in the documentation [Drives.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/drives/list)  the client library is built directly from the same source that builds the docs.     As for reading email you need to go though the gmail api not the drive api

Comment: If you are looking for the PHP API documentation, you can get it [here](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v3/php/latest/index.html). For the common documentation, [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/drives/list).

Answer (score 1):

I notice that the sample code only shows query parameters using the files.list. In order to gather the Shared drives of the organization you would need

> drive.list

You can also test it yourself to give you an idea from their [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/drives/list). Make sure to select "true" as a Super Admin so you can get all the Shared drives from the domain.

The closest available documentation I was able to find with references to Shared Drives can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v3/php/latest/class-Google_Service_Drive_TeamDriveList.html). You might find dificult to search for example codes or data for it, this could be because the original name was "Team Drives". Which could explain the lack of available documentation for PHP samples with the name "Shared Drives".

Based on that I was able to find some useful references that could help you. "List shared drives from Google Drive"

```js
$service->teamdrives->listTeamdrives()->getTeamDrives();
```

This sample code was found over this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54449267/google-teamdrive-getchildren-of-a-teamdriveid-php). It might be old, however all the API calls for Shared Drives in V3 use the term "teamDrives".

I would like some clarification to the second question:
Help me get the email of the user.